# How to add tabs on JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I have a JPanel with a table on it. On that same JPanel, I want to add another table but as a totally separate table.  So I want two tabs button somewhere on the top to interchange between the two tables. (first tab to stay on default table, clicking on second tab will go to the other table).

How do I go about in my code so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Font; 
import javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource; 
import java.util.Calendar; 
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.table.*;

class table extends JFrame 
 {
    // Instance attributes used in this example
    private JPanel      topPanel;
    private JTable      table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private static JFrame openFrame;

    public table ()
    {

    //.....{some code work deleted to simplify}....

    String columnNames[] = {"Time","Volume","Rate","CPP"};

    String dataValues[][]= new String [counter][4]; 


for (int i= 0; i<counter; i++){
dataValues[i][0] =dataValues_timemap[i];}

for (int j = 0; j<counter; j++){
dataValues[j][1] = dataValues_vol[j]; }

for (int k = 0; k<counter; k++){ 

dataValues[k][2] = dataValues_rate[k]; }    

for (int l = 0; l<countery; l++){
dataValues[l][3] = dataValues_cpp[l]; }


        setTitle("Table Summary");
        setSize(280,300);

        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        getContentPane().add( topPanel );
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(1300,280);
        table = new JTable( dataValues, columnNames );

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );

}
    }

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        // Create an instance of the test application
        SimpleTableExample mainFrame    = new SimpleTableExample();
        mainFrame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: The convention in Java is that classes are capitalized `public Table()`. This would make your code easier to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `JTabbedPane`. It solves exactly this problem.

The `JTabbedPane` can be added as a child of your `JPanel`.